# Synchronize a Select Projection

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, projection, subquery

I would like to use a table alias within the projection of another select statement, like this:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Name]
      ,CASE WHEN 'reptile' IN 
      (SELECT [Type] FROM dbo.Pets [S] INNER JOIN [P] ON S.People_ID = P.ID) 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [HasReptile]
  FROM People [P]
```

Within the projection there is a select statement, which is trying to use the table alias [P].  Evidentally this is not legal.  How can I achieve my goal without using two separate queries?

In effect, my query is saying "show '1' for any person who owns a pet of type 'reptile'.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Name]
      ,CASE WHEN 'reptile' IN 
      (SELECT [Type] FROM dbo.Pets [S] WHERE S.People_ID = P.ID) 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [HasReptile]
  FROM People [P]
```

Comment: Yup, that caught me by surprise.  I figured if the INNER JOIN didn't work, a WHERE clause wouldn't either.  But this is my answer.